# Discriminator , WrongClassException JPA with Hibernate backend

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a requirement to have an abstract superclass.

I have 6 subclasses for that abstract superclass.

I mapped them with the SINGLE_TABLE inheritance strategy in JPA.

In another POJO I have a one to many relationship with these 1+6 classes.

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "mSearchPreference", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<SearchCriteria> mSearchCriteria;
```

here "SearchCriteria" is the abstract class.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SRCH_CRTR_T", schema = "LPEW")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "SRCH_DISCRIMINATOR_CDE", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
@org.hibernate.annotations.ForceDiscriminator
public abstract class SearchCriteria extends BaseDBObject implements Comparable<SearchCriteria>
```

and it has 6 concrete subclasses classes like

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("DATE")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
public class SearchCriteriaDateRange extends SearchCriteria
```

I can insert the values into the table, but when I am retrieving I get an error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.WrongClassException: Object with id: 261 was not of the specified subclass: com.lmig.lit.lpew.model.criteria.SearchCriteria (Discriminator: DATE  )
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getInstanceClass(Loader.java:1453)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceNotYetLoaded(Loader.java:1284)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1206)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:580)
    at org.hibernate.loader.L
10:57:44,786 INFO  [STDOUT] oader.doQuery(Loader.java:701)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:236)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadCollection(Loader.java:1994)
    at org.hibernate.loader.collection.BatchingCollectionInitializer.initialize(BatchingCollectionInitializer.java:52)
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.initialize(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:565)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.onInitializeCollection(DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.java:63)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.initializeCollection(SessionImpl.java:1716)
    at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:344)
    at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:86)
    at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.readElementExistence(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:142)
    at org.hibernate.collection.PersistentSet.add(PersistentSet.java:187)
    at com.lmig.lit.lpew.model.homescreen.HomeScreenPreference.addSearchCriteriaByType(HomeScreenPreference.java:132)
    at com.lmig.lit.lpew.model.homescreen.HomeScreenPreference.addSearchCriteriaByType(HomeScreenPreference.java:147)
    at com.lmig.lit.lpew.service.LpewUserServiceImpl.initializeHomeScreenPreferences(LpewUserServiceImpl.java:135)
    at com.lmig.lit.lpew.service.LpewUserServiceImpl.findUserAndInitialize(LpewUserServiceImpl.java:103)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:307)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:182)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:149)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:106)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    at $Proxy122.findUserAndInitialize(Unknown Source)
    at com.lmig.lit.lpew.jsf.beans.UserSession.getLpewUser(UserSession.java:989)
    at com.lmig.lit.lpew.jsf.beans.RequestForServiceBean.getAllRequests(RequestForServiceBean.java:263)
    at com.lmig.lit.lpew.jsf.beans.RequestForServiceBean.getAllNewRequests(RequestForServiceBean.java:382)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:62)
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:53)
    at com.sun.faces.el.FacesCompositeELResolver.getValue(FacesCompositeELResolver.java:64)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:97)
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:186)
```

Does anyone know the solution?

Comment: is it the problem with discriminator or problem with lazyinitialization?

Comment: How do you load the instances, by an explicite query, or implicite by navigate throw an association? And is lazy loading involved?

Comment: navigating through an associating. i mentioned those annovations onetomany relationship through that relationship i am loading, yes i am lazily loading the instances.

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/q/42599203/4424739 It's works for me.

Comment: Try this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48788554/4424739 It's works for me.

Comment: Try this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48788554/4424739 It's works for me.

Answer (score 16):

you should use `@org.hibernate.annotations.DiscriminatorOptions(force=true)` on your root entity

Comment: Adding @DiscriminatorOptions(force = true) to the superclass worked for me, but I'm using a Hibernate feature whereas I would prefer to stay on the JPA side. Any suggestions for that? Eager fetching alone didn't fix the problem.

Comment: Same problem 10 years later, and this save my day! Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Your stack trace looks like if you are layz loading an set of SearchCriteria enities.

for example:
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "mSearchPreference", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Set mSearchCriteria;

The problem is that Hibernate can't know the proper subclass without loading the entity.
So if the set is created by lazy loading, hibernate first create proxies of type SearchCriteria for all entities in the set. If the concreate instance is loaded later, than there is no way to exchange the not concreate enough proxy by the right one.

> So, the "fix" is to not use proxies.
>   And this means that you either have to
>   use eager loading (lazy="false") or
>   lazy="no-proxy". The latter option
>   requires byte-code manipulation of the
>   compiled classes to make Hibernate
>   intercept the call to the getter
>   method (see
>   http://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/v3/re
>   ... properties). I have no experience
>   with this method, but it seems like a
>   good candidate for your case.

https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=996047&start=0

Comment: On the other hand the exception looks like that there is an other problem - check your discriminator column for entity 261 - it is only guesing:but the exception contains one whitespace to much.

Comment: if i keep the (fetch = FetchType.EAGER) i am getting still getting the lazyinitializationexception, but in my application all the other lazy fetching and eager fetchings are working fine, but this is the only instance of inheritence mapping in our application so i am fighting.

Comment: yes DATE is having one white space, i changed in the DATABASE but still same problem.

Comment: i browsed so many sites forums some where somebody mentioned to use force discriminator, i tried it but tat was also not working.

Comment: Now the (all) Whitespaces are fixed, and you changed the association to EAGER fetch - and you still get the SAME exception?

Comment: sorry i changed the value thru TOAD but it is not changing may be i dont have write access to the DB, in my POJO i dont hav white spaces but how it is inserted as white spaces is .. yah got it i have set the length of discriminator to 6 for that reason the 2 empty white spaces are coming, i am not getting prblm with string adn bolean they r exactly 6, is this 2 white spaces really causing the problem.?

Comment: Thank Ralph, i got the solution, thank you for your time and quick response, the problem is ( silly problem man stuck up for 1 whole day) finally got it, in my table the discriminator column is character (6) here i am inserting DATE as only 4 characters, remaining 2 it is inserting spaces return also coming with spaces it is not trimming before comparing and throwing exceptions. silly, silly problem yaar but very tricky...