# WrongClassExceptionObject:object with id:22 was not of the specified subclass ,only for new entries.old entries are working fine

Tags: java, xml, spring, hibernate

I an using Ejb,Spring+hibernates in my application.
My application fetches a row from DB and based on its discriminator column value(entry1,entry2,entry3...) it connects to the JavaClass file which is marked in the  tag of my tablename.hbm.xml file and code gets executed.

All my old code is working fine, 
I have added a new.java file ,and when i tried to add a new entry to the `tablename.hbm.xml` file i am facing the below error.

> org.springframework.orm.hibernate.HibernateobjectRetrivalFailureException:
>   object with id:22 was not of the specified subclass:(path of table1 related class)(Discriminator :entry1)
>   nested exception is net.sf.hibernate.WrongClassException : Object with id:22 was not of the specified subclass:(path of table1 related class)(Discriminator :entry1)

There are no duplicates in my table neither any space issues.
none of my new entires are getting executed.Is it due to my .hbm.xml file not getting refreshed everytime.please let me know for any suggestions.

Comment: I tried all the solutions present in stackoverflow but none of them worked.

Answer (score 0):

Simply, add to project file properties following:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.discriminator.ignore_explicit_for_joined=true
```

It is works for me.